# I need help solving a simple exercise (I'm new, so it's all like heiroglyphics to me)

Tags: javascript, curl, phantomjs

I have to figure out a way to return the titles of all the articles on the front page of slashdot.org within 72 hours. I really have no idea where to even begin, any suggestions?

Comment: You have 72 hours from now to accomplish this or the algorithm should return its results within 72 hours?

Comment: @tsh if you can figure how to contact me through my profile, I can probably help you with this.

Comment: lol naomik how do I contact you I can't find an email on your profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open Slashdot.org
2. Right-click on headline and select "Inspect element" (Chrome)
3. Do this again with another headline
4. Check for similarities in html-code (like classes)
5. Loop through all elements with same class and write them to an array
6. Write a function that loops through that array and returns each element of the array

Comment: Where do I write the code in terminal or in sublime?

Comment: Where do you need to return the titles to?

Comment: Doesn't matter. whatever is easiest or makes the most sense

Comment: I mean in your task. How do you have to return them?

Comment: Any way I can. It was suggested I use phantomjs/casperjs. I've learned more about what those are, but now I need to figure out the right commands to automate the task. I've got: page.open ("slashdot.org"), so far.